# Show check marked rows from UITableView on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a selection list that allows users to select rows. After a row is selected, a checkmark is shown and the `cell.textLabel.text` value is saved as an array on `NSUserDefaults`.

What I am having trouble on, is when the user comes back to make the accessoryView checkmark from NSUserDefaults (from previous occasions).

Here is the current code:

```
if ([[userDefaults objectForKey:@"selectedProducts"]) isEqualTo:cell.textLabel.text] {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

However, I get an error as an invalid approach. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**: If I print `NSLog(@"%@", [userDefaults objectForKey:@"selectedProducts"])` I get the following:

```
2014-08-16 21:26:01.749 Abonos[575:60b] (
    "Product 1",
    "Product 2",
    "Product 3",
    "Product 4"
)
```

Comment: If possible then update your question with output of   NSLog(@"%@",[userDefaults objectForKey:@"selectedProducts"]), it can help us to understand.

Comment: Post the actual error message.

Comment: @rdelmar - The error message is the following: ``No known instance method for selector 'isEqualTo:'``

Comment: @AnandK - I have updated the question with the Log. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you should enumerate over all values for every cell

```
for(uint i=0 ;i<[userDefaults objectForKey:@"selectedProducts”].count ; i++)
{
    if([[[userDefaults objectForKey:@"selectedProducts”]objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:cell.textLabel.text])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice approach, however it does not seem to work. After checking, I found that the problem is that the ``if`` is returning false. I have check the array for ``userDefaults`` and it is working correctly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. I was copying the code to the ``viewDidLoad`` method. The correct way is in the ``cellForRowAtIndexPath`` method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `[userDefaults objectForKey:@"selectedProducts"]` returns an array. However, you're trying to compare that array that you returned to an `NSString`, which would never evaluate to true. You need to get the array and iterate through its values, comparing each to the cell text value using `isEqualToString:` (not `isEqualTo`).

Comment: If I change ``isEqual:`` to ``isEqualToString:`` the app crashes and I get the following log. ``2014-08-16 21:31:51.255 App[598:60b] -[__NSCFArray isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10920e780
2014-08-16 21:31:51.278 App[598:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10920e780'``

Comment: Yes. You're getting an array of strings back from your user defaults. In your original code, you are comparing an array to a string so it will never evaluate to true. You need to iterate through the array and compare each string value to the text in the label.